# Looking for a way to extract values from array, add them up and push to new array

Tags: php, arrays

I have been working at this for a little while now and cannot seem to find a solution.

I am starting with an array like this:

```
[
    [
        'username' => 'test',
        'amount' => 1.05
    ],
    [
        'username' => 'test',
        'amount' => 2.05
    ],
    [
        'username' => 'test',
        'amount' => 3.05
    ],
    [
        'username' => 'demo',
        'amount' => 4.10
    ],
    [
        'username' => 'demo',
        'amount' => 4.10
    ],
    [
        'username' => 'demo',
        'amount' => 2.10
    ]
]
```

And I am ultimately looking to end up with an array like this:

```
[
    [
        'username' => 'test',
        'total' => 6.15
    ],
    [
        'username' => 'demo',
        'total' => 10.30
    ]
]
```

As you can see, I am trying to extract the amount values for each user, add them up and push to a new array with the username and the total amount added up.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can simply iterate through each element of the array and populate a multi-dimensional associative array with in the form `Array['username']['total']`.

```
function sumByUsername($array)
{
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        $output[$item['username']]['total'] += $item['amount'];
    }

    return $output;
}
```

so using your test data:

```
$output = sumByUsername($input);
var_dump($output);
```

You'd get an array like:

```
//    array(2) {
//        ["test"]=>
//      array(1) {
//            ["total"]=>
//        float(6.15)
//      }
//      ["demo"]=>
//      array(1) {
//            ["total"]=>
//        float(10.3)
//      }
//    }
```

To get the exact output you specified, add the following line to the loop:

```
function sumByUsername($array)
{
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        $output[$item['username']]['username'] = $item['username']; // <-----
        $output[$item['username']]['total'] += $item['amount'];
    }
}

//    array(2) {
//      ["test"]=>
//      array(2) {
//            ["username"]=>
//        string(4) "test"
//            ["total"]=>
//        float(6.15)
//      }
//      ["demo"]=>
//      array(2) {
//            ["username"]=>
//        string(4) "demo"
//            ["total"]=>
//        float(10.3)
//      }
//    }
```